# Parsing JSON from site to Windows Phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm attempting to parse the JSON on http://gothere.sg/a/search?q=688609+to+changi+airport&ll=1.362083%2C103.819836 to a Windows Phone 8 app.

Currently, I'm using the Newtonsoft.Json framework but don't really know how to use it to parse the data. I'm also using json2csharp.com to see the data easily.

The data I need is `List<string> email` and `string route_html` under `Route`, if I'm not wrong.

How would I use Json.NET, or any other method, to parse the above two into my app?

Edit: My current non-working code:

```
        private async void testCode()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://gothere.sg/a/search?q=688609+to+changi+airport&ll=1.362083%2C103.819836");
        var client = new HttpClient();

        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
            JToken token = JObject.Parse(response);
            var token1 = token.SelectToken("route_html").ToString();
            var token2 = token.SelectToken("email").ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: First, that is a LOT of data, and even using an online editor, it is a lot to sift through. I could not easily find the fields you were looking for. Second, I would suggest you look through the documentation for [Json.net documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/). It's not hard to get used to, and should clear up some of your confusion.

Comment: Try reading the documentation for Json.net and play with it, and if it still didn't work post here what you tried and we'll try to help you.

Comment: Added what I have so far. Not sure how to target a particular Class though. Probably doing it the wrong way :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you use json2charp you get a lot of classes. Add those to your project.

Then use the following to get the root object.

```
RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);
```

Then to get your List email: root.directions.drive.routes.email.

Answer (score 1):

as per my opinion Newtonsoft.Json is very easy for parsing Json.

Just follow bellow step

**Step1:** Add Service References by right click on add References.

**Step2:** Now put your web service link on Service References and press go button, And also add Namespace of service Reference 
[image]

**Step3:** Now add using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;` name space in your .cs file

**Step4:** Now add bellow code in your cs file

```
 WhatsupServices.WhatsUpServiceSoapClient ws = new WhatsupServices.WhatsUpServiceSoapClient();
ws.ContactUsJSONCompleted += ws_ContactUsJSONCompleted;
ws.ContactUsJSONAsync(txtContactUsName.Text, txtContactUsPhone.Text, txtContactUsEmail.Text, txtContactUsComment.Text);
```

**step6:** now genrate your resopnce method

```
 void ws_ContactUsJSONCompleted(object sender, dynamic e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(LogIn.NetworkBusyMsg, LogIn.MsgHdr, MessageBoxButton.OK);
                busyIndicator.IsRunning = false;
            }
            else
            {
                busyIndicator.IsRunning = false;
                string Result = e.Result;
                JObject obj = JObject.Parse(Result);
                string ResultCode = (string)obj["ResultCode"];
                string ResponceMessage = (string)obj["ResponseMessage"];

                if (ResultCode == "1")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Thank you for your message. We'll get back to you soon.", LogIn.MsgHdr, MessageBoxButton.OK);
                    NavigationService.GoBack();
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Hope it will help you.

If any query than comment here.I wll help you